# Show button when another button is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, linkbutton

I have a search button on a filter and when this is clicked I need to show another button. This button goes not trigger a post back so the page doesn't refresh and the button never shows. When the page first loads a bool called DelStatus gets set to true. After I click the search button, if this is true I need to show `btnEPODToExcel`. I've tried changing the style, changing the visibility and changing the display from javascript:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DelStatus == true)
    {
        btnEPODToExcel.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
        btnEPODToExcel.Visible = true;

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Message",
                                               "<script>$(document).ready(function () { ShowEPODExcel();});</script>");
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function ShowEPODExcel()
            {
                document.getElementById('<%= btnEPODToExcel.ClientID %>').style.display= "block";
                $('#<%= btnEPODToExcel.ClientID %>').show();
           }
```

Button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEPODToExcel" CssClass="btnToExcel" Width="100px" ToolTip="Download Result to Excel" OnClick="btnEPODToExcel_Click" Text="EPODs to Excel" />
```

Comment: did you try to fire an alert to be sure that your script is working well?
is there any problem about using jquery's onclick function?

Comment: Check if your function ShowEPODExcel is called. If it is executed check the attributes of the button after rendering.

Comment: @ReadyFreddy the function ShowEPODExcel isn't getting called. Have a made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @KalyanBasa the function ShowEPODExcel isn't getting called.

Comment: to give a direct answer, we need to see head section of aspx file to be sure you added script as well. Can you post it please?

Comment: @ReadyFreddy its a MasterPageFile it doesn't have a head section

Comment: So what about your MasterPage's head section? You mean this is a page that uses master page right? Master pages must have a head section already.

Comment: seems like there is no problem. Did you try my jquery solution. Also can you please check Chrome DevTool console after click button to see if there is any error about JScript. On your webform on Chrome, right click to page -> Inspect -> Console from top bar.

Comment: Also that is the script block that i used //<script type ="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>//. Can you please add this also if you didn't.

Comment: @ReadyFreddy that didn't work. ShowEPODExcel still isn't getting called

Comment: There is no function as ShowEPODExcel at Jquery example that i gave below. click function at jquery working good when i try this. Really can't understand the problem. As i said that check if there is any JScript error at Chrome Console when you click to button. Also try to clear your chrome cache.

Answer (score 0):

are you  calling a JS function  when btnSearch clicked (Client click) and it returns false..?

if not try to remove  btnSearch_Click method and recreate it

Comment: This seem to be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: because i cannot comment anywhere at this moment , except in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no problem about using JQuery, you can try that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnSearchClick").on('click', function () {
        window.alert("Hello");
        document.getElementById('btnEPODToExcel').style.display = "block";
        $('btnEPODToExcel').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

But it will not postBack simply. If you want to make a postback action, my only advise can be that hold a Session to show or hide this button. Change Session value in `btnSearchClick_Click` method and by Session value, set display of button on `Page_Load`.

If you don't even get "Hello" alert, probably you made a mistake while adding Javascript to your form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that btnSearch_Click is called. I would suggest you to do the following changes to your code.

**Button**:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEPODToExcel" style="display:none" Width="100px" ToolTip="Download Result to Excel" OnClick="btnEPODToExcel_Click" Text="EPODs to Excel" />
```

**Code-behind**:

```
if (DelStatus == true)
{
    btnEPODToExcel.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If Nothing works for you than store the value of Delstatus in a hidden field instead of bool and than play with it using javascript.
Another way is to try @kalyan Basa answer